# NSPredicate that evaluates to true if an evaluated string contains 3 or more characters contained in a given string

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, swift, nspredicate

The title pretty much says it - I am trying to write a predicate that can take a given string, and check whether or not another string contains at least three letters that my given string has. This is regardless of character order and capitalization, and includes duplicate occurrences of a letter. An example use of this would be, if I have a massive array of three letter words, I want to be able to pass a string with six characters (or an array of six, single character strings?) into this predicate and use it to evaluate whether or not any of the three letter words in my array are comprised of any three of the six letters I've passed in (duplicates included).

I was thinking it would be something along the lines of :

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] .{3,}%@",<array of characters>];
```

But I know that syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Regex cannot do it this way. You should consider other approaches.

Comment: It's unclear ("duplicates included"). Do you have some sample with "valid" or not, and when there are "duplicates"? Else if you are okay with using blocks: `[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSString *  _Nullable evaluatedObject, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nullable bindings) {if ([evaluatedObject length]<3){return NO;} NSUInteger count = 0; for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [myString length]; i ++){ NSString *subString = [myString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)]; if ([evaluatedObject rangeOfString:subString].location != NSNotFound){ count ++; if (count > 3) return YES;}} return NO;}];`

Answer (score 0):

To check create the predicate, try

```
SWIFT:
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF contains %@", "abc")
```